# Using traversal by pointers on const array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to loop through a constant array of integers using pointers. My code is as follows:

```
void printArrayPointer(const int arr[], int n){
    for (int *i = arr; i < arr + n; i++) {
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
}
```

This gives me an error telling me that there is an invalid conversion from const int* to int*. I know how to do this using traversal by index (as in using the index of the elements in the array) but I'm trying to use pointers for this code.

Comment: Listen to what the compiler is telling you. Why not declare `i` as a pointer to a `const int`?

Comment: Use `const int*` instead of `int*`.

Comment: That worked. How come this is possible, since I clearly increment i every time I go through the for loop?

Comment: `const` refers to what the pointer points to, not the pointer itself.

Comment: `i`is not const but what it points to is. You can increment it but not dereference it and change it.

Comment: @Evan You wouldn't be able to increment the pointer if you declared it `const int * const i;`

Comment: @Evan Generally, types make more sense when read right-to-left than they do when read left-to-right.  With this in mind, cv-qualifiers can usually be read as applying to whatever's to their left, or if there's nothing to their left, as applying to whatever's closest to them.  `const int*` and `int const*` are both "pointer to `const int`", for example, and `int* const` is "`const` pointer to `int`".

Comment: (Note, though, that references to pointers can be a bit strange.  For example, `const int*&` is "reference to `const int*`, while `int* const&` is "`const` reference to `int*`.  This difference can be important sometimes.  I believe it can also show up with pointers to pointers, but I believe those are less common than references to pointers.)

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler already told you, there is an error in the line:

```
for (int *i = arr;...
```

`arr` is `const int[]`, `i` is `int *`. If the compiler allows `i` to be initialized with a `const int *` then the subsequent code can change the `const` values stored in `a` using `i`, because `i` is a pointer to non-const data. That's the reason the code doesn't compile and the compiler tells you in the error message.

You have to declare `i` as `const int *i` and it will work.

```
void printArrayPointer(const int arr[], int n){
    for (const int *i = arr; i < arr + n; i++) {
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [axiac said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885847/using-traversal-by-pointers-on-const-array/41885930#41885930), you must write `for (const int* i ...` because arr is a `const int*`.

The reason that you can still increment `i` is that `const int*` means that what is at `i` cannot be changed, by you can still change what `i` points to. So you cannot change the values in the array, but you can change the const pointer that iterates through them.

To make it so that you can't change what a pointer points to, you would have to declare it like this:  `int* const i`. Then you *could* change what is at `i` but not what `i` points to. You could also make it so that neither could be changed, which could be written as `const int* const i`.